# Explain Stefan-Boltzmann Law?

Tags: temperature, radiation, thermal-radiation

Can someone explain the [Stefan-Boltzmann law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law) in an easy-to-understand way?

Comment: Have you looked at the [Wikipedia entry on the subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law)?

Comment: Yes, but it is a little hard for me to understand. Can you explain it in a simpler way?

Comment: I think the Wiki article is pretty simple, and *maybe* I could explain it more simply *if* you told me *what* it is that you don't understand.

Comment: @KyleKanos The OP asks for an easy model, pictures, motivation, no formulas, simple words... For me, the Wikipedia article is the *opposite* from what is wanted here.

Comment: A web search would give many other resources that are less detailed than Wikipedia and would appear to give an adequate answer. I think this question in its current form displays a serious lack of effort.

Answer (score 1):

The energy per time ("power") in the radiation due to heat ( the infra-red "light" that you see using a night vision) scales with the temperature $T$ of a body like $T^4$

Comment: Doesn't make sense... What is "energy per time" and "see using a night vision" and "temperature of a body like T^4"? Don't get it.

Comment: (I omitted that $T$ is supposed to be the temperature as usual) Do you have problems with the words per se? Explaining those would be hard, e.g. seeing is what you do with your eyes..

Comment: Don't know how to make it simpler than this. The hotter a thing is, the more heat and light comes from it. In fact, for double the temperature, you get sixteen times more heat and light :-p

Comment: Possibly you could add that it also depends linearly on the emitting area.